# RedisStore.prototype.__proto__ = Store.prototype

Tags: node.js

I have no experience with NodeJs. I am trying to run app.js file from command prompt using node command and i am getting this error

```
 D:\Imports\sparkleshare-dashboard\node_modules\connect-redis\lib\connect-redis.j
s:96
  RedisStore.prototype.__proto__ = Store.prototype;
                                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at module.exports (D:\Imports\sparkleshare-dashboard\node_modules\connect-re
dis\lib\connect-redis.js:96:41)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Imports\sparkleshare-dashboard\app.js:12:42)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

here is my app.js file

```
   /**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var express = require('express');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var i18n = require("i18n");

var config = require('./config');
var errors = require('./error');
var utils = require('./utils');

var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);
var redis = require('redis'), redisClient = redis.createClient();

var app = null;
if (config.https.enabled) {
  var fs = require("fs");
  var privateKey = fs.readFileSync(config.https.key);
  var certificate = fs.readFileSync(config.https.cert);
  app = module.exports = express.createServer({ key: privateKey, cert: certificate });
} else {
  app = module.exports = express.createServer();
}

var session = express.session({ secret: config.sessionSecret, store: new RedisStore() });

i18n.configure({
    locales: ['en', 'cs', 'de', 'el']
});

// Configuration
app.configure(function(){
  var lf = utils.getLoggingFormat();
  if (lf) {
    app.use(express.logger(lf));
  }
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.set('basepath', config.basepath);
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if ('x-forwarded-proto' in req.headers && req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] == 'https') {
      req.connection.encrypted = true;
    }
    next();
  });
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.compiler({ src: __dirname + '/public', enable: ['sass'] }));
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(i18n.init);
  app.use(app.router);
});

var FolderProvider = require('./folderProvider').FolderProvider;
var folderProvider = new FolderProvider(config.folders);
var DeviceProvider = require('./deviceProvider').DeviceProvider;
var deviceProvider = new DeviceProvider(redisClient);
var UserProvider = require('./userProvider').UserProvider;
var userProvider = new UserProvider(redisClient, deviceProvider);
var LinkCodeProvider = require('./linkCodeProvider').LinkCodeProvider;
var linkCodeProvider = new LinkCodeProvider();

var middleware = require('./middleware');
middleware.setup(userProvider, deviceProvider, folderProvider, linkCodeProvider);

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true })); 
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(errors.errorHandler);
  app.use(express.errorHandler()); 
});

function auth(login, pass, next) {
  userProvider.findByLogin(login, function(error, user) {
    if (!user) {
      return next(new Error('Invalid login'));
    }

    if (user.checkPassword(pass)) {
      return next(null, user);
    } else {
      return next(new Error('Invalid login'));
    }
  });
}

// Dynamic helpers
app.dynamicHelpers({
  messages: require('express-messages'),
  user: function(req, res) {
    return req.currentUser;
  },
  basepath: function() {
    return this.set('basepath');
  }
});

app.helpers({
  convertSize: function(bytes) {
    var unit = 0;
    while (unit < 3 && bytes >= 1024) {
      unit++;
      bytes /= 1024;
    }

    return (Math.round(bytes * 100, 2) / 100).toString() + " " + ["", "Ki", "Mi", "Gi"][unit] + "B";
  },
  __i: i18n.__,
  __n: i18n.__n
});

// Routes
app.all(/^(?!\/api\/).+/, function(req, res, next) {
  session(req, res, next);
});

require('./api')(app, deviceProvider, folderProvider, middleware);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.redirect('/login');
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.session.destroy(function(){
    res.redirect('home');
  });
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  userProvider.getUserCount(function(error, count) {
    if (count < 1) {
      res.redirect('/createFirstUser');
    } else {
      if (req.session.user) {
        res.redirect('/folder');
      } else {
        res.render('login');
      }
    }
  });
});

app.get('/createFirstUser', middleware.userDbEmpty, function(req, res) {
  res.render('createFirstUser', { formval: {} });
});

app.post('/createFirstUser', middleware.userDbEmpty, function(req, res) {
  var reRenderForm = function() {
    res.render('createFirstUser', {
      formval: req.body
    });
  };

  if (!req.body.passwd1) {
    req.flash('error', i18n.__('Password could not be empty'));
    return reRenderForm();
  }

  if (req.body.passwd1 != req.body.passwd2) {
    req.flash('error', i18n.__('Passwords must match'));
    return reRenderForm();
  }

  userProvider.createNew(req.body.login, req.body.realname, req.body.passwd1, true, [], function(error, user) {
    if (error) {
      req.flash('error', error);
      reRenderForm();
    } else {
      res.redirect('/login');
    }
  });
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res){
  auth(req.body.login, req.body.password, function(error, user) {
    if (error) {
      req.flash('error', error);
      res.render('login');
    } else {
      if (user) {
        req.session.regenerate(function(){
          req.session.user = user;
          res.redirect('back');
        });
      } else {
        req.flash('error', error);
        res.render('login');
      }
    }
  });
});

app.get('/changeProfile', middleware.isLogged, function(req, res) {
  res.render('changeProfile', {
    formval: req.currentUser
  });
});

app.post('/changeProfile', middleware.isLogged, function(req, res, next) {
  var reRenderForm = function() {
    res.render('changeProfile', {
      formval: req.body
    });
  };

  var updatePassword = false;
  if (req.body.new1) {
    if (req.body.new1 != req.body.new2) {
      req.flash('error', i18n.__('Passwords must match'));
      return reRenderForm();
    }

    updatePassword = true;
  }

  var user = req.currentUser;
  if (updatePassword) {
    user.setPassword(req.body.new1);
    req.flash('info', i18n.__('Password updated'));
  }
  user.name = req.body.name;

  userProvider.updateUser(user, function(error) {
    req.flash('info', i18n.__('Profile updated'));
    res.redirect('back');
  });
});

app.get('/manageUsers', [middleware.isLogged, middleware.isAdmin], function(req, res, next) {
  userProvider.findAll(function(error, u) {
    if (error) { return next(error); }
    res.render('manageUsers', {
      users: u
    });
  });
});

app.get('/modifyUser/:uid', [middleware.isLogged, middleware.isAdmin, middleware.loadUser], function(req, res, next) {
  folderProvider.findAll(function(error, folders) {
    if (error) { return next(error); }
    res.render('modifyUser', {
      u: req.loadedUser,
      folders: folders
    });
  });
});

app.post('/modifyUser/:uid', [middleware.isLogged, middleware.isAdmin, middleware.loadUser], function(req, res, next) {
  folderProvider.findAll(function(error, folders) {
    if (error) { return next(error); }

    var u = req.loadedUser;
    u.name = req.body.name;
    u.admin = req.body.admin == 't' ? true : false;
    u.acl = req.body.acl ? req.body.acl : [];

    userProvider.updateUser(u, function(error) {
      req.flash('info', i18n.__('User updated'));
      res.redirect('back');
    });
  });
});

app.get('/deleteUser/:uid', [middleware.isLogged, middleware.isAdmin, middleware.loadUser], function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('deleteUser', {
    u: req.loadedUser
  });
});

app.post('/deleteUser/:uid', [middleware.isLogged, middleware.isAdmin, middleware.loadUser], function(req, res, next) {
  var reRenderForm = function() {
    res.render('deleteUser', {
      u: req.body
    });
  };

  var u = req.loadedUser;

  userProvider.deleteUser(u.uid, function(error) {
    if (error) {
      req.flash('error', error.message);
      reRenderForm();
    } else {
      req.flash('info', i18n.__('User deleted'));
      res.redirect('/manageUsers');
    }
  });
});

app.get('/createUser', [middleware.isLogged, middleware.isAdmin], function(req, res) {
  res.render('createUser', { formval: {} });
});

app.post('/createUser', [middleware.isLogged, middleware.isAdmin], function(req, res) {
  var reRenderForm = function() {
    res.render('createUser', {
      formval: req.body
    });
  };

  if (!req.body.passwd1) {
    req.flash('error', i18n.__('Password could not be empty'));
    return reRenderForm();
  }

  if (req.body.passwd1 != req.body.passwd2) {
    req.flash('error', i18n.__('Passwords must match'));
    return reRenderForm();
  }

  userProvider.createNew(req.body.login, req.body.realname, req.body.passwd1, req.body.admin == 't', [], function(error, user) {
    if (error) {
      req.flash('error', error);
      reRenderForm();
    } else {
      req.flash('info', i18n.__('User created'));
      res.redirect('/manageUsers');
    }
  });
});

app.get('/publicFolder/:folderId', function(req, res, next) {
  folderProvider.findById(req.params.folderId, function(error, folder) {
    if (!folder.pub) {
      next(new errors.Permission('This is not a public folder'));
    } else {
      var filename = req.param('name');
      if (!filename) {
        filename = 'file';
      }
      res.attachment(filename);

      folder.getRawData(req,
        function(error, data) {
          if (error) { return next(error); }
          res.write(data);
        },
        function(error, data) {
          if (error) { return next(error); }
          res.end();
        }
      );
    }
  });
});

app.get('/recentchanges/:folderId?', middleware.isLogged, middleware.checkFolderAcl, function(req, res, next) {
  folderProvider.findById(req.params.folderId, function(error, folder) {
    if (error) { return next(error); }
    folder.getRecentChanges(req, function(error, data) {
      if (error) { return next(error); }
 
      res.render('recentchanges', {
        data: data,
        folder: folder
      });
    });
  });
});

app.get('/folder/:folderId?', middleware.isLogged, middleware.checkFolderAcl, function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.params.folderId) {
    folderProvider.findAll(function(error, folders){
      if (error) { return next(error); }

      utils.aclFilterFolderList(folders, req.currentUser);

      res.render('folders', {
        folders: folders
      });
    });
  } else {
    folderProvider.findById(req.params.folderId, function(error, folder) {
      if (error) { return next(error); }

      if (req.param('type') == 'file') {
        var filename = req.param('name');
        if (!filename) {
          filename = 'file';
        }
        res.attachment(filename);

        folder.getRawData(req,
          function(error, data) {
            if (error) { return next(error); }
            res.write(data);
          },
          function(error, data) {
            if (error) { return next(error); }
            res.end();
          }
        );
      } else {
        folder.getItems(req, function(error, list) {
          if (error) { return next(error); }

          var curPath = req.param('path');
          var parUrl = null;

          if (curPath) {
            var parPath = curPath.split('/');
            parPath.pop();
            parPath = parPath.join('/');
            parUrl = querystring.stringify({
              path: parPath
            });
          }

          res.render('folder', {
            folder: folder,
            tree: list,
            path: curPath,
            parUrl: parUrl
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }
});

app.get('/download/:folderId', middleware.isLogged, middleware.checkFolderAcl, function(req, res, next) {
  folderProvider.findById(req.params.folderId, function(error, folder) {
    if (error) { return next(error); }
    var headersSent = false;
    var maybeSentHeaders = function() {
      if (headersSent) {
        return;
      }
      headersSent = true;
      var filename = 'archive';
      var path = req.param('path');
      if (path && path != '') {
        filename += '-' + path.replace(/[^\w\d-]/, '_');
      }
      filename += '-' + req.params.folderId.substring(0, 8) + '.zip';
      res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '"'
      });
    };
    folder.createArchive(req, function(error, data) {
        if (error) { return next(error); }
        maybeSentHeaders();
        res.write(data);
      },
      function(error, data) {
        if (error) { return next(error); }
        maybeSentHeaders();
        res.end();
      }
    );
  });
});

app.get('/linkedDevices', middleware.isLogged, function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.currentUser.admin) {
    deviceProvider.findAll(function(error, devices) {
      if (error) { return next(error); }
      
      r = function(logins) {
        res.render('linkedDevices', {
          devices: devices,
          logins: logins
        });
      };

      var logins = {};
      userProvider.findAll(function(error, users) {
        var count = users.length;
        if (count === 0) {
          r(logins);
        }
        users.forEach(function(user) {
          logins[user.uid] = user.login;
          if (--count === 0) {
            r(logins);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  } else {
    deviceProvider.findByUserId(req.currentUser.uid, function(error, devices) {
      if (error) { return next(error); }
      res.render('linkedDevices', {
        devices: devices
      });
    });
  }
});

app.get('/linkDevice', middleware.isLogged, function(req, res) {
  var schema = config.https.enabled ? 'https' : 'http';
  var url = schema + '://' + req.header('host');

  if (config.externalUrl) {
    url = config.externalUrl;
  }

  res.render('linkDevice', {
    url: url
  });
});


app.get('/unlinkDevice/:did', [middleware.isLogged, middleware.loadDevice, middleware.owningDevice], function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('unlinkDevice', {
    d: req.loadedDevice
  });
});

app.post('/unlinkDevice/:did', [middleware.isLogged, middleware.loadDevice, middleware.owningDevice], function(req, res, next) {
  var d = req.loadedDevice;

  deviceProvider.unlinkDevice(d.id, function(error) {
    if (error) {
      req.flash('error', error.message);
      res.render('unlinkDevice', {
        d: req.loadedDevice
      });
    } else {
      req.flash('info', i18n.__('Device unlinked'));
      res.redirect('/linkedDevices');
    }
  });
});

app.get('/modifyDevice/:did', [middleware.isLogged, middleware.loadDevice, middleware.owningDevice], function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('modifyDevice', {
    d: req.loadedDevice
  });
});

app.post('/modifyDevice/:did', [middleware.isLogged, middleware.loadDevice, middleware.owningDevice], function(req, res, next) {
  var d = req.loadedDevice;
  d.name = req.body.name;

  deviceProvider.updateDevice(d, function(error) {
    req.flash('info', i18n.__('Device updated'));
    res.redirect('back');
  });
});

app.get('/getLinkCode', middleware.isLogged, function(req, res) {
  var code = linkCodeProvider.getNewCode(req.currentUser.uid);
  var schema = config.https.enabled ? 'https' : 'http';
  code.url = schema + '://' + req.header('host');

  if (config.externalUrl) {
    code.url = config.externalUrl;
  }

  res.contentType('application/json');
  res.send(code);
});

// always keep this as last route
app.get('/stylesheets', function(req, res, next) {
  next();
});

app.get('*', function(req, res, next){
  next(new errors.NotFound(req.url));
});

function runApp() {
  app.listen(config.listen.port, config.listen.host, function() {
    console.log("SparkleShare Dashboard listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
  });

  if (config.fanout.enabled) {
    var fanout = require('./fanout/fanout');
    fanout.listen(config.fanout.port, config.fanout.host, function() {
      console.log("SparkleShare Fanout listening on port %d", config.fanout.port);
    });
  }
}

// upgrade database

require('./upgrade').upgrade(redisClient, runApp);
```

Comment: What versions of `express` and `redis`?  Did you see this note: https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis#usage

Comment: @Joe how can i check the version of module?

Comment: @umerk44 see the `package.json` file and `dependencies` key it should be listed there

Comment: @Joe thanks you showed me the right path, i was using connect redis 1.5.6 and now i am using 1.4.7 this solve me issue. Do you have fimiliarity with sparkleshare, because now i am getting another error.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed: I changed my code to:

```
var session = require('express-session')
, RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
```

Comment: When I was using , it is giving me Syntax Error:Unexpected Token